# Unable to parse JSON using dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am parsing this JSON:

```
[{
    "cities": [
    {
        "city": "Pune",
        "state": "Maharashtra"
    },
    {
        "city": "Mumbai",
        "state": "Maharashtra"
    },
    {
        "city": "Panaji",
        "state": "Goa"
    },
    {
        "city": "Hyderabad",
        "state": "Andhra Pradesh"
    },
    {
        "city": "Banglore",
        "state": "Karnataka"
    },
    {
        "city": "Chennai",
        "state": "Tamil Nadu"
    },
    {
        "city": "New Delhi",
        "state": "New Delhi"
    }]
}]
```

using Dojo code:

```
var content = "<table border = 1><tr><th>City</th><th>State</th></tr>";
dojo.forEach(jsonData.cities, function (jsonData)
{
    // Build data from the JSON 
    content += "<tr><td>" + jsonData.city + "</td><td>" + jsonData.state + "</td></tr>";
});
content += "</table>";
```

However a table with no elements is displayed! What exactly do I need to change in my Dojo code?

Comment: you might want to use `jsonData[0].cities` in `dojo.forEach`

Comment: Or remove the outermost square brackets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
var DObject = [{
    "cities": [
    {
        "city": "Pune",
        "state": "Maharashtra"
    },
    {
        "city": "Mumbai",
        "state": "Maharashtra"
    },
    {
        "city": "Panaji",
        "state": "Goa"
    },
    {
        "city": "Hyderabad",
        "state": "Andhra Pradesh"
    },
    {
        "city": "Banglore",
        "state": "Karnataka"
    },
    {
        "city": "Chennai",
        "state": "Tamil Nadu"
    },
    {
        "city": "New Delhi",
        "state": "New Delhi"
    }]
}]
var output = "";
for(var i in DObject[0].cities) {
  var detail = DObject[0].cities[i];
  output += "<tr><td>" + detail.city + "</td><td>" + detail.state + "</td></tr>";
}
alert(output);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/f6cFq/5/)

Comment: Can you please explain how the index `DObject[0].cities` works?

Comment: DObject is array.array contains object,first object index is cities so only specify [0] to get details

Comment: array.array? I did not understand.

Comment: DObject is array that contains object,first object is cities so only specify [0] to get details